# JSON to Backbone.js Model

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

How can I send JSON to the initialization of a model? I am trying to make the model dynamic based on a form:

```
v = new ModelObject($('#form-id').serializeJSON());
```

But this stores the form data as just one attribute and an object. I'd like to use the JSON attributes as the model attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get a better serializer. I built one called Syphon, specifically to do this with backbone:

https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.syphon

```
var data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(someViewWithAForm);

var model = new Backbone.Model(data);
```

Or Ben Alman's `serializeObject` jQuery extension: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject

Answer (score 1):

You can populate the model with form data by using this code:

```
var data = {};
$.each(this.$("#formId").serializeArray(), function(index, val) {
  data[val.name] = val.value;
});
```

then call save or init the moduel with the data.

```
var demo = new My.Dynamic.Model(data);
```

or

```
var demo = new My.Dynamic.Model();
demo.save(data);
```